# Why vue replaces static page title with Vue App

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am working on very simple one-page html project. It's static.html that is suppose to load data from external local file and generate some graphs/charts/etc. I am using Vue and I am stuck.

1. My public/index.html hasdefault content like follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon/black.png">
        <title>DummyTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without
                JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And there is something I do not understand. After yarn build, dist/index.html has content as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vue App</title>
    <link href=css/app.9288aca6.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=js/app.2c3ec05b.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=js/chunk-vendors.6fa5766d.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=css/app.9288aca6.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script src=js/chunk-vendors.6fa5766d.js></script>
    <script src=js/app.2c3ec05b.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What the hell happened? Why title has changed to Vue App and where is favicon? I was looking for similar questions and problems and found nothing what would help me **understand** why is that.

Comment: Do you have ```public``` folder in project root ? Also, are you using webpack ?

Comment: sure, I guess it happens because i've changed name of index.html to dummy.html as described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890879/how-to-rename-index-html-on-a-vue-js-build)
by adding to vue.config.js

`module.exports = {
  indexPath: 'dummy.html'
}`

Comment: Ok. I need to see exact config and project structure. If you have your code somewhere, I can  take a look if it doesn't work

Comment: https://gitlab.com/MikoShoi/vuedraft

Comment: try it out https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think there shouldn't be any specific reason to rename `html` file in `public` directory from `index` to `dummy`.

1. If you only need output name as `dummy` in `dist` folder, then rename `html` file in `public` folder to index and use this in `vue.config.js`. This will solve the issue.

   ```
   module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/',
    indexPath: 'dummy.html'
   }
   ```
2. If you need `html` file to be named as `dummy`, both in project structure and `dist`, just use this in `vue.config.js`. This will solve the title issue. Refer this official doc link [Vue Config Docs Link](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages)

   ```
    module.exports = {
     pages: {
         index: {
           // entry for the page
           entry: 'src/main.js',
           // the source template
           template: 'public/dummy.html',
           // output as dist/index.html
           filename: 'dummy.html'
         }
     },
     publicPath: '/',
     indexPath: 'dummy.html'
   }
   ```